# Point Domain to Azure Container

Tags: url, dns, ip, hostname

I have a GoDaddy domain `myexample.es` and an Azure Container Instance holding a landing page at `my-example.eastus2.azurecontainer.io`.

I've configured a 301 redirect but it changes the `http://myexample.es` to `http://my-example.eastus2.azurecontainer.io` in the browser URL.

**I'd like to be redirected to the container (at `http://my-example.eastus2.azurecontainer.io`) when hitting `http://myexample.es` while keeping `myexample.es` in the browser URL.**

Answer (score 1):

A **temporary solution** I've found was to create an **A record** pointing from `@` to the ip address of my container instance.

However, I'm not sure if this ip address can change over time or after restarting the container..

The best possible solution, I think, would still be redirecting from `myexample.es` to `my-example.eastus2.azurecontainer.io` while keeping the former, instead of showing the latter, in the browser URL.

Comment: have you found a way to do that?